# Anyone else finding the refreshed UX a bad experience on mobile

Tags: discussion

Accessing the question list I now see a huge header and 2 questions, where the votes and answer counts are (for me) less obvious and visible and where tags are more prominent.

The previous arrangement worked better for me, and I wondered what others thought.

[image: mobile experience SUX]

Comment: I don't access on mobile, so can't speak to personal experience or compare to previous looks. But your screenshot looks to me what I like to call *(I literally just made this up but I had to say that to make it sound better)* Suspect User eXperience. Or for those Among Us players or teenagers among us: Sus UX. Or just SUX, for short.

Comment: It's not just you. I find the new format much more obnoxious as well. I think I actually ended up resorting to using the Request Desktop Site mode on my phone.